# Is null-byte injection possible in Java filenames?

Tags: attacks, appsec, java

---

From the [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/it-security/8434#8434)

Comment: Also directory traversal attacks. Remember to use whitelists (better avoid any kind of trusting of untrustworthy data).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Accordingly to the following resources:

- [Null byte attacks are alive and well](http://blog.portswigger.net/2008/05/null-byte-attacks-are-alive-and-well.html)
- [Null Byte Injection](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null-Byte-Injection)
- [Java Null Byte injections](http://i8jesus.com/?p=9)

we can conclude that Null Byte injections are possible in Java.

Comment: As Dave Wichers' answer, this is historically correct for OpenJDK until 2013. Now fixed, that's not to say you shouldn't, say, whitelist characters in filenames.

Comment: It's "according to" ... anything below a 6 character edit won't go through though. So perhaps someone seeing this comment will fix it and flag my comment for deletion. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Null byte injection depends on a mismatch in the way that strings are handled.

e.g. Java stores the length of the string independently of the content of the string, while C starts at the beginning of the string and checks for a Null Byte to indicate the end of the string.

As a result, Java code can perform checks like "does the file requested end with .jsp" on a string like "/etc/shadow%00.jsp" (where %00 represents the null byte), and return true, while passing this string to "new FileInputStream()" will result in the underlying OS (both Windows and Linux) trying to open "/etc/shadow".

(Relevance of trying to open /etc/shadow on Windows is left as an exercize for the reader :-) )

Answer (score 7):

Null byte injection in filenames was fixed in Java 7 update 40 (released around Sept. 2013), https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8014846 . So, its FINALLY fixed.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update Dave. Can you provide a link, and some more technical details?

Comment: @AviD Do you want to change the accepted answer? http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8014846

Comment: Sure, if you want to expand this in to a proper answer... :-)